# Jupyter notebook started asking password all of a sudden

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I haven't made any fresh installations to Jupyter notebook. I've been using the scripts of my colleague who has resigned and have been running the scripts from his folder. They are saved in a shared drive. I've been running those scripts for the past 2 months and there has been no issue. However, today Jupyter notebook started to ask for token/password all of a sudden.

[image]

Can someone please tell me how to fix this?
There are no tokens in my url. My URL is as follows

```
http://10.100.51.125:8888/login?next=%2Fnotebooks%2Flocky%2FoneOffOrAdHoc%2FoptimizelyExperiments%2FCRO%2520-%2520Automation%2520end-to-end%2520OneChoice-Old%2520Experiments.ipynb
```

For running these scripts I have never launched Anaconda prompt.
Could you please also tell how I was able to run those scripts, because I've always used jupyter notebook on localhost and can see what is running in anaconda in the Anaconda prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so it was just a password within the team that the team uses. It was not a password that I set. It was a universal password that the team setup and since I was working in the same environment, that password was applicable to me too.